# How can I figure out the order of running jetty.base and jetty.home in jetty?

Tags: linux, jetty

I'm using Jetty 9,I have jetty.base and jetty.home, and I want to know when I start jetty, in what kind of order it call the jetty.base and jetty.home, I mean at first it'll read the library from jetty.base or jetty.home?or it check the property form jetty.base then check from jetty.home or vice versa, if you know any useful article, or any way to test it inside my jetty, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--list-config` option and look at the output.  It tells you the order.

```
$ java -jar /opt/jetty/jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612/start.jar --list-config

Java Environment:
-----------------
 java.home = /home/joakim/java/jvm/jdk-8u45/jre
 java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
 java.vm.version = 25.45-b02
 java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
 java.vm.info = mixed mode
 java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
 java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_45-b14
 java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
 user.dir = /home/joakim/static-base
 user.language = en
 user.country = US

Jetty Environment:
-----------------
 jetty.version = 9.3.0.v20150612
 jetty.tag.version = master
 jetty.home = /opt/jetty/jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612
 jetty.base = /home/joakim/static-base

Config Search Order:
--------------------
 <command-line>
 ${jetty.base} -> /home/joakim/static-base
 ${jetty.home} -> /opt/jetty/jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612


JVM Arguments:
--------------
 (no jvm args specified)

System Properties:
------------------
 (no system properties specified)

Properties:
-----------
 jetty.port = 8080

Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 11 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:                    3.1.0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar
 1:                 3.1.0.M0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
 2:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
 3:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
 4:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
 5:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
 6:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
 7:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
 8:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
 9:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.0.v20150612.jar
10:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml
```

Notice the section titled "Config Search Order"?

Comment: so it will run jetty.base (every library and configuration) then it'll run the jetty.home!? I mean is it always true? and if it's always true what would happen to those same properties and .. that the configuration is different ? it'll override them or augment them?

Comment: The configuration is specified in your `${jetty.base}/start.ini` (for basic usage) or `${jetty.base}/start.d/*.ini` (for advanced usage).  Whatever you have configured (modules, libraries, properties) is what the server will use.    The existence of something in `${jetty.base}` or `${jetty.home}` means nothing, only the configuration means something.